# How to generate a SecureRandom array, convert it to a string, and then convert it back to array

Tags: java, cryptography

Here below is how I generate a `SecureRandom`:

```
byte[] arr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(32);
```

then, I convert it to a string like this:

```
String str = new String(arr)
```

and finally, I try to convert the string back to my original byte array:

```
byte[] arr2 = str.getBytes()
```

The problem is that the last statement does not return my original byte array... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then, I convert it to a string like this:

Don't do that!

You have two problems here:

- this constructor will use the default encoding;
- even if you used UTF-8 as an encoding, some byte sequences just cannot be encoded to `char`s!

You should *not* use `String` to hold binary data; or use a string-based encoding, such as Base64.

For more information, see [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and [`CodingErrorAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html).

Comment: and one other after 2 years ;)